# Angular 5 How to create PDF URL?

Tags: angular

I receive a base64 string of a PDF file from a REST server. I want the PDF to display in a window. But I'm having trouble creating the URL. The resulting invoicePdfURL looks like this:

```
blob:https://localhost:4200/dc391fef-25fb-4dcf-921b-779384182920
```

I am in control of the REST server, and can have it return anything suitable. In this example, it's returning a base64 string, I have also had it return a byte[], but am having the same problem.

What's the correct way to code this?

**Here's component.ts:**

```
  public invoicePdfURL: SafeResourceUrl;
  ...

  public getInvoicePDF() {              
    this.invoiceService.getInvoicePDF(this.rowID)
      .subscribe( base64Data => {              
        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(atob(base64Data).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));  

        const binaryData = [];
        binaryData.push(byteArray);

        const blob = new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/pdf"});

        this.invoicePdfURL = this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, 
                             this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(URL.createObjectURL(blob)));
        console.log("this.invoicePdfURL: " +this.invoicePdfURL);
    });
  }
```

**Here's component.html:**

```
  <button class="btn btn-danger pull-left" onclick="window.open('{{invoicePdfURL}', '_blank')">
    <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download PDF
  </button>
```

Comment: And what should the url look like?

Comment: It turns out that the blob: url that I posted above is correct. The problem was the component.html. Trying to pass the url within braces {{}} wouldn't work, so I changed it to inject the html. I posted the answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

The blob URL is correct, the problem was in how I was trying to pass it to the component.html. I fixed it by injecting the html, as shown below. I also refactored the component.ts.

**component.ts:**

```
  public getInvoicePDF() {  

    this.invoiceService.getInvoicePDF(this.rowID)
      .subscribe( base64Data => {

        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(atob(base64Data).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
        const blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf'});

        this.invoicePdfURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);        

        this.downloadPdfHTML =
          `
            <button class="btn btn-danger pull-left" onclick="window.open('` +this.invoicePdfURL +`', '_blank')">
              <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download PDF
            </button>
          `;
    });
  }
```

**component.html:**

```
  <div [innerHTML]="downloadPdfHTML | safeurl: 'html'"></div>
```